# T - Spawn to Mid Window Smoke Mirage

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've been trying to perfect this smoke for CS:GO on mirage but cannot seem to get it exactly. Has anyone tried this and found a better or more efficient way to do it?

Comment: 64 tick or 120 tick srevers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the flight time is a bit different from 64 ticks servers, to 120 ticks servers, I'll post both of them.

You will also need a jumpthrow bind to do it consistently.

1. Open up console
2. Type in:

   > alias "+jumpthrow" "+jump;-attack"
   >   alias "-jumpthrow" "-jump"
   >   bind "h" "+jumpthrow"
3. Change  <kbd>H</kbd>  to the keyboard button you want for the bind.

   - [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTHNvldqOjQ) for 64 ticks servers
   - [album for the 120 tick servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJLA9.jpg)